# How to agree to iTune Connect agreement update?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I am told I need to agree to the updated Agreement. If I follow the links, I get to a page where I can download the .pdfs but there's no option to agree to them.

The help documentation and video show pages I don't see.

On my Membership page I'm told I agreed to the Terms and Conditions on 1st May 2016.

[image]

Edit: This is on Firefox Windows and Safari on OSX, so it's presumably not a browser issue.

Comment: Contact iTunes Connect Support.

Comment: Have done, but I'm really needing a faster response. There must be people who have hd this agreement. What do they see different to me? Is there an 'agree' option somewhere?

Comment: Call support, fastest way possible:  https://developer.apple.com/contact/phone

Comment: Hmmm. Apple phone support sent me some useful documentation ... the stuff I've already tried on the website which is 4 years old and doesn't match the current interface. They also provided the iTunes Connect support phone number but gave me the wrong office times. But I emailed them and they've asked for details on the URL that is misbehaving. Well I don't know if there's a web problem or account problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the new agreement section wasn't showing because my account was up for renewal at the end of this month. I renewed and the Accept T&C option appeared.

So the issue here is you don't appear to have full Apple Developer privileges in the final month of your membership. If you're having problems and you're account is up for renewal, consider that as a possible cause.